# How the heck can I POST this file to Google?

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, http-post

I have been working on this for days, and have it working in 5 different languages, yet Java refuses to cooperate!

I am attempting to POST a Flac file to the Google Speech recognition servers, yet I am always getting back an error telling me that my Flac file is bad.

This is my code, I am going nuts, can someone please point out my mistake?

```
File file = new File("./test.flac");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file) );
String         line = null;
StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
    stringBuilder.append( line );
}

String bob = stringBuilder.toString();
bob = URLEncoder.encode(bob, "UTF-8");  
URL google = new java.net.URL("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US");
WebRequest test = new WebRequest( google, HttpMethod.POST);
test.setAdditionalHeader("Content-type", "audio/x-flac; rate=16000");
test.setRequestBody( bob );
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
System.out.println( webClient.getPage( test ).getWebResponse().getContentAsString() );
```

Comment: Why are you opening an audio file as a text file?

Comment: How else am I supposed to read it in and create a string for submitting it?

Comment: don't submit a string.  Read in bytes using a stream and write out bytes to a `URLConnection`'s output stream.

Comment: Dumped HtmlUnit and used HttpClient, it provides more options for the POST body.